# PostgreSQL + Node Integration

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

Need some advice regarding the following situation:
There is an existing PostgreSQL database that I would like to draw information from (with full authorization of course). How can I query the entries in that database using NodeJS? I know sequelize can offer what I'm looking for, but I'm a bit confused as to how to approach this. I've heard that I would have to migrate the data first in order to then query it. What's the best way to go about doing this? Thanks.

For reference, I've taken a look at this link (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3791) but haven't gotten what I'd hoped out of it.

Comment: Google search + articles is a good start before asking questions like that. Welcome to 2017.

Comment: Wow man, you're so kind! I was actually stuck in 2004. Thanks so much man!

Answer (score 0):

You can query without migration for existing database, this package should help https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg